# How do I factor this conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian, bayesian-network

I am having a brain freeze.   Could you show the steps to get from line 1 to line 2?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You must have a condition: $D$ is independent of $\omega$ given $\theta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can't. The second term in the first line, i.e. $p(\theta|\omega)$ corresponds to second and third terms in the second line, i.e. $p(\theta|\omega)p(\omega)$, which means you need to have $p(D|\theta,\omega)=P(D|\theta)$. It means $D,\omega$ are independent given $\theta$, as also noted in the comments. Probably, in your book, there is context indicating this information, e.g. a Bayes net or an experimental setup. A possible scenario is $D$ is your coin toss experiment, $\theta$ is your head probability of your coins. And $\omega$ is a parameter in the prior of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I missed the part where a hierarchical model implicitly assumes D,ω are independent.  Was trying my best to do algebra and couldn't get it work.